# GameObject prefab is not showing in scene when activated in my script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I have 2 classes attached to 2 different GUIs, PlayerInfoGUI and DiplomacyGUI.

I am trying to have a method in PlayerInfoGUI create a list of buttons dynamically which, when clicked will then pull up DiplomacyGUI. (Both GUIs as well as the dynamic buttons have their own prefabs created)

My PlayerInfoGUI class dynamically populates a panel with buttons using the PopulatePlayerList method.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class PlayerInfoGUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image[] guiElements;
    public GameObject playerInfoButtonPrefab, canvasParent;
    public GameObject diplomacyMenu;

    void Awake ()
    {
        PopulatePlayerList (GameEngine.competingPlayers);
    }

    void PopulatePlayerList (List<CompetingPlayer> players)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++) {
            GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate 
            (playerInfoButtonPrefab);
            Button playerInfoButton = go.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button> 
                                                                         ();
            CompetingPlayer receivingPlayer = players [i];
            playerInfoButton.onClick.AddListener (() => handleDiplomacyMenu 
                                                         (receivingPlayer));
            go.transform.SetParent (canvasParent.transform, false);
        }
    }

    public void handleDiplomacyMenu (CompetingPlayer receivingPlayer)
    {
        diplomacyMenu.SetActive (true);
    }
}
```

The listener on the PlayerInfo Button is firing when clicked, but the diplomacyMenu GameObject is not showing up in the scene. Most of the research I have read says this should be a simple diplomacyMenu.SetActive(true), or a diplomacy.gameObject.SetActive(true), but this doesn't work.

I have confirmed that the code is being run, but the object cannot be seen.
 Thank you in Advance!

[PlayerInfoPrefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alKKA.png)

[PlayerInfoButtonPrefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYUFd.png)

[DiplomacyPrefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXSHn.png)

Comment: Post your code not the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Edited it in.

Comment: The first two prefabs, seems like they are saved as inactive.

Comment: You want to change the state of your `Object Instance`, however you are changing your `Prefab's` state. Instead you should do like you have done above and instantiate an `Object instance` of your `Prefab` and then change that instance's state.

Comment: I got it working with the .Instantiate(diplomacyMenu) in front of the .setactive() thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using diplomacyMenu.gameObject when diplomacyMenu is already a game object, this might cause issues. Also make sure the prefab that is represented by diplomacyMenu has its children enabled. I think SetActive() just sets the top level parent to enabled, not any nested objects.

Comment: I had used both diplomacyMenu.gameObject.SetActive(), and diplomacyMenu.SetActive() and neither seemed to work, but I was confused by the useage. Thank you for clearing this up. The diplomacy menu I am trying to pull up is the parent object, so no issues there.

Comment: No problem, also I don't think my answer should be marked as the best answer. My response didn't seem to directly solve your problem.